# Can't Reach Go Rest API Behind Nginx With SSL Through HTTPS

Tags: reactjs, docker, go, nginx, ssl

I am running a Golang rest api on a digital ocean server on `127.0.0.1:8080`, and a React Frontend on `127.0.0.1:3000`. I've setup my Nginx to use SSL, and when I visit my site at `wwww.xxx.yyy.com` it routes me to `https`. My Nginx config currently looks like this:

```
upstream app {
    server app:8080;
}

upstream interface {
    server ui:3000;
}


# http to https
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name xxx.yyy.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;


    server_name xxx.yyy.com;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=4838400; includeSubDomains";
    add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/key.key;


    #  listen to React Server.
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://interface;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

The issue is that I'm not able to reach my api through my broswer at `https://xxx.yyy.com/api` as I get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. Now when my frontend tries to reach it I get in the console logs:

```
Mixed Content: The page at was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure form action ..... This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I am telling my React app to reach my api through `http://127.0.0.1:8080` as I was under the impression from reading online that I could have my services run on HTTP and let Nginx deal with the SSL. However I can't seem to get that working. If I change the address to point towards HTTPS I then get a different error `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` which I assume is simply because my rest api is not setup to handle SSL.

If anyone can provide some guidance, I'd very much appreciate it!

Comment: Could you check which requests were blocked by the browser. Maybe your page tries to load javascript over insecure connection? For sure your interface should use `https://xxx.yyy.com/api`, because it runs in the browser and if you use localhost as an API server address it will try to contact contact computer on which the browser is running. You could try to open `https://xxx.yyy.com/api` in browser to confirm that ssl works properly.

Comment: `I was under the impression from reading online that I could have my services run on HTTP and let Nginx deal with the SSL.` yes. This is a common practice. But then this has little to do wth the Go language

Comment: When you send a request for a website there are many more requests that happen in the background. meaning a page loads CSS/JS and other files. What could be happening is that initial request is on HTTPS, but then subsequent requests have MIXED content. this can be changed can often be dealt with using http_proto/schema in nginx. Aside your docker app, might need to change the response as well. this is why @Jaroslaw said about checking the browser.